# Issue syncing Exchange 2003 account email after ICS update

Tags: email, exchange, active-sync

After upgrading to ICS on my Samsung Galaxy S2, I no longed receive e-mail from one of the Exchange accounts configured in the stock e-mail app.

The Exchange 2010 account works fine. The Gmail account works fine as well. However, for the Exchange 2003 account, my phone only syncs the calendar. I receive no e-mail, although I am able to send e-mail from the same account. I have tried removing and adding the account, with no luck. I have also tried to change from Manual to Push notifications. No luck.

Could this be related to the security profile? Any way that I can force an update of this profile?